# OAuth2.0 with horizontally scaled servers

Tags: spring, rest, oauth-2.0

I am writing a simple Spring REST api, which I plan to integrate with Oauth2.0 authentication for security. I am aware of the authentication flow and the refresh and access tokens.

My Question is if I horizontally scale my server app, how can clients talk to different servers with access tokens received from another server? Does the client have to authenticate with the other servers too?

Comment: Does your horizontall scaled servers all provide the same Service (it is just a replication because of performance)?

Answer (score 0):

Typically in such kind of a deployment you will have one Authorization server and all the other servers will accept the token, validate it with the Authorization server and then serve the request. Check the layout below. You can have a couple (at least 2) to avoid single point of failure of the authorization server.

So in the flow below client can go to server1, 2 or 3 but they will essentially do the same.

There are other ways but this simpler.

[image]

Comment: The above works for both replicated services or different services.